# How to move files older than y days from Archival folder to somefolder using python in Databricks

Tags: python-3.x, databricks

I have to find all files older than y days in archival folder and move those files to somefolder.I have found some files older than y days in archival and tried moving to other folder.i have written code using python.while running the code i'm getting this error "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dbfs/FileStore/Archival/testparquet.parquet".I have checked,file exists in dbfs .Can someone please help me on this

```
from pathlib import Path
import arrow
import os, time, sys
vFilePath="/dbfs/FileStore/"
path = "/dbfs/FileStore/Archival/"
path1="dbfs:/FileStore/Archival/"
#####FOR Dbutils path###
vDbuPath="/FilsStore/Archival/"
deleteFullPath="FileStore/Deleted/"
now = time.time()
print (now)
vdelFullPath=deleteFullPath+"/"
for f in os.listdir(path):
  Filename=str(print(f))
  print(Filename)
  f = os.path.join(path,f)
  print(os.stat(os.path.join(path,f)).st_mtime)
  if os.stat(os.path.join(path,f)).st_mtime < now - 1 * 86400: 
      print("f value: "+f)
      filename=os.path(f)
      print("dbutilspath: " +filename)
      if not os.path.exists("dbfs:/"+deleteFullPath + Filename):         dbutils.fs.mv(filename,"dbfs:/"+deleteFullPath+"testparquet.parquet",recurse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using hadoop filesystem. Below you will get a list of dictionnaries with the file dates and names.
You can then do your magic to move the files if they are old enough.

```
import time
from time import mktime
from datetime import datetime 
list_of_files=[]
fs = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
path_exists = fs.exists(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(source_dir))
if path_exists == True:
  file_list = fs.listFiles(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(source_dir), True)
  while file_list.hasNext():
    file = file_list.next()
    list_of_files.append({'filedate' : datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(time.localtime(int(str(file.getModificationTime())[:-3])))),"filename" : str(file.getPath())})
```